# How can you generate a sysid with PHP?

Tags: php, database

I worked with ServiceNow for many years. They have a very interesting database.
Every record in the entire database has a field called the said. This number combined with a table name makes that record unique amongst all the ServiceNow databases in the entire world.

if you transfer a data record from your ServiceNow database into any other ServiceNow database in the world that sysid will remain the same.

I’m trying to create a function to do this with PHP. how would you even do that?

Comment: Welcome to webmasters.  Unfortunately this question is not a good fit for the site - its really about programming, so I'd recommend posting it on stackexchange.com (or maybe databases.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know an application with lots of database tables. Each record has a blargh identifier that is unique across all blarghs in the world. Do you think they're the same as sysids?

I can't tell you how to create a "sysid". I can tell you about things like UUIDs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).